# Explaining what exactly opposite magics are

Tags: magic, balancing-magic-systems

In my magic system, there are three contours of magic; three ways magic can be used. **Breathers**, **Binders**, and **Breakers**.

**Breathers** conjure ether(magic) to aid the user. For example, *Flamecharm* conjures ether to create combustion and burn matter at will. Proficiency in Breathers comes from the use of one's breath, a.k.a. spirit.

**Binders** use ether to enhance the user's body. Binders are any magic technique that relates to a user's body, basically not elementals. For example, *Riftcut* uses ether to create rifts in reality to teleport the user's *body* places. Proficiency in Binders comes from binding as much ether as possible to the user's body.

**Breakers** use ether to manipulate existing things. For example, *Ironsing* uses ether to manipulate metals and magnetism. Proficiency in Breakers comes from "breaking" existing matter, a.k.a. manipulating it.

There are essentially infinite techniques of these contours of magic, so I'm trying to use opposites as a good way to balance out the magics and not make different magics better than others. I think all should have their weaknesses and strengths and every magic user should be able to beat another magic user no matter what type of magic they use.

How do I make opposite magics that make sense? Fire and ice being opposites would make sense, but what exactly makes one magic opposite to another? Water could be the opposite of fire, but also an opposite to earth, and earth could be another opposite to water. But then what is the opposite of wind? Earth? Lightning/Thunder? How could I create a method of explaining what exactly an opposite magic is or how to define opposite magic?

Comment: I think for us to give a definition of something you can't define is an impossibility. Why not first come up with a decent concept (or even find a good example) and then ask for improvements or sophistication here?

Comment: @cowlinator I don't believe it is: 'opposite' can be interpreted in many ways.

Comment: @cowlinator no, it's not "well defined" in the context of imaginary non-existing concepts. Neither water, nor fire, nor earth magic exists. There is no definitive way to claim what the relation between them *is*, given that it depends on whoever authors them for the purpose they are authored.

Comment: Why not start by looking at some of the pre-existing magical systems - the water/air dyad seems popular, why do you chose to reject that (on what basis)?

Comment: We need more details about your magic system is elemental based or not?

Comment: You can make opposite magics make sense however you want, depending on what makes sense for you. You can also define and explain opposite magics however you want. Given the highly subjective nature of your questions (you really should edit this down to 1) and vastness of the possibility space for creating, explaining, and defining opposite magics, no amount of additional amount of information about your magic system will make this question suitable for this site.

Comment: I've an issue understanding the meaning of some of your words. Please explain "conjure".. do you mean Breathers *produce* all ether ? in that case it seems the other two "contours of magic" depend on the Breathers. Opposite Breather magic would take away ether.. But how is 'opposite' to be defined for the other two ?

Comment: I'll just make another question better clarifying this stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Frame challenge: Magic forces are messy

Many fictional magical systems with opposing forces do not follow a simple bi-directional opposites scheme, and instead follow a more complex set of rock/paper/scissors relationships. This allows each force to have contrasts with multiple other forces, rather than keeping all forces separated into strictly opposite pairs. The messiness can allow for more player freedom in mixing and matching strategies.

---

#### Example 1: Pokemon

Pokemon has about 15 pokemon types, which are each like schools of magic. 
Here is one 5-type cycle:

- Water has an advantage over Fire (because water extinguishes fire)
- Fire has an advantage over Ice (because fire melts ice)
- Ice has an advantage over Ground (because ice makes potholes?)
- Ground has an advantage over Electric (because its grounded)
- Electric has an advantage over Water (because water conducts)

But each of these types also has relationships with several other types as well. It's more of a web of type relationships than clean-cut cycles.

---

#### Example 2: Magic the Gathering

In Magic, there are 5 colors of magic arranged in a "color wheel", and each is "opposite" of two others.

- White represents order/law/civilization
- Blue represents knowledge
- Black represents ambition/greed
- Red represents passion/chaos
- Green represents nature

Each opposite pair has some conflict that is distinct from the others.

- White/Black - Society vs Self-Interest
- Blue/Red - Planning vs Impulse
- Black/Green - Death vs Life
- Red/White - Chaos vs Order
- Green/Blue - Nature vs Technology

Comment: You can even extend this to other elemental systems, especially Asian systems where *wood* and *metal* are considered fundamental elements. (Well, at least these elements are translated as "wood" and "air")

Answer (score 5):

Things are opposite when they are generally mutually exclusive. Something is (generally) either frozen/wet OR on fire. The ancient Greeks considered earth to be opposite air because things were generally solid and heavy OR soft/fragile and weightless.

Basically you create opposites in magic the same way you would create opposites in anything else. Pick an attribute or property. For example, "Living". Then think of an attribute that is mutually exclusive. "Dead". Now you have life magic and death magic. Optionally, you can have them represented by things that exemplify or are archetypes of that, in the way that "air" and "earth" represent "heavy" and "light". For example (for life vs death): "wood" and "metal".

It helps if the attribute is pretty objective and not opinion-based, so everyone is in agreement about it.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be to look at two proposed opposites and try to figure out what exactly is opposite/inverse/reversed between them.

For instance, Fire and Ice. One is an abundance of heat while the other is a lack of heat. You could say that fire powers are at the opposite end of a spectrum from ice powers.

Similarly with Light and Dark. Opposite ends of an illumination spectrum.

But you have to get creative to fit everything into this kind of idea. Such as, Earth vs Air? Opposite ends of the solidity spectrum, I guess? Seems a little weird. On the other hand, you could separate Air into two things: Blowing and Sucking - opposites on the pressure spectrum.

So taking this scheme and running with it is really up to your creativity as well as however much handwaving you're willing to do when things don't quite fit the way you might like.